# How to throw a 404 error from htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Everything I find seems to be about created a custom 404 page.

*That is **not** what I am trying to do.*

If I want to block access to a page I can do this in htaccess:

> RewriteRule *pattern* - [F]

However, "**Forbidden**" hints that the page ***does*** exists. I want the page to appear to not even exist. So I would like to give a 404 error instead of a 403. Then have it render whatever 404 page would render if the resource really wasn't there.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hey @JD Isacks -  it'd be great if you'd accept an answer :)

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect) and [AskApache](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument/) suggest that you can simply use `Redirect 404`.

Comment: So simple! Thanks :-) In case it helps anyone else, I customised my message too by adding a line before it with: 
`ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>My message</H1>"`

Answer (score 5):

`Redirect 404` will work but will execute across all domains pointing to your vhost. Since you're using multiple domains, you'll want to use `RewriteRule`:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^microsite\.someotherexample\.net$
RewriteRule ^path/to/page/?$ - [R=404,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 404
```

And check you have on the Apache configuration the `AllowOverride` sentence with `FileInfo` or `All` to allow this type of .htaccess.

Comment: `Redirect` is from mod_alias and, therefore, doesn't require `RewriteEngine` from mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

...what about actually *removing* it (or renaming it, or moving it away...)?

What's the point anyway of having it there if you want to make it not accessible at all?

Comment: I want it accessible to one domain and not another. I have more than one domain pointing to the same server. Most of the pages slightly adjust based on domain (logo, description, etc.) Some resources should appear to only be on 1 domain though.